# Can TikZ emulate PSTricks' inline \Rnodes, scattered along a complex equation?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, pst-node

PSTricks' `\Rnode` makes it easy to add annotations to a complex equation typeset by (La)TeX:

[image: PSTricks inline \Rnode]

Simply add `\Rnodes` around existing elements of the equation, and the mathematical typesetting is preserved.  How is this achieved in TikZ, with the same simplicity?

The LaTeX code which produced the above example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}

\raisebox{0ex}[4ex][5ex]{ 
$\rule{0ex}{5ex}
R^{\alpha \beta} - 
{1 \over 2}R g^{\alpha \beta} + 
g^{\alpha \beta} \Lambda 
=
\frac{8 \pi G}{c^4 \mu_0} 
\left( 
  F^{\alpha}{}^{\Rnode{a}{\scriptstyle\psi}}   % <---- 1st \Rnode
  F_{\Rnode{b}{\scriptstyle\psi}}{}^{\beta} +  % <---- 2nd \Rnode
  {1 \over 4} g^{\alpha \beta} F_{\psi\tau} 
  F^{\psi\tau}\right)
\ncbar[linecolor=blue,angle=-90,nodesep=1pt,arm=2ex]{<->}{a}{b}$ }

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, `pstricks` is no longer needed as you load `pst-node`.

Comment: Thanks. I edited the question to remove \usepackage{pstricks}.

Comment: Yes and it is known as `\tikzmark`. http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2013/04/beware-the-tikzmark-my-son/

Comment: Take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/83911/86

Comment: Ah, no.  Not that one.  That's for subnodes of existing nodes.  For free floating nodes, you need tikzmark.

Comment: Related: [Is there a TikZ equivalent to the PSTricks `\ncbar` command?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55068)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, it is relatively easy to do with TikZ:

Place nodes with

```
\tikz[baseline, rememeber picture]
  \node[anchor=base, inner sep=+0pt, outer sep=+0pt] (<name>) {<text>};
```

The combination of `baseline` and `anchor=base` puts `<text>` on the already established baseline and `inner sep=+0pt` and `outer sep=+0pt` makes sure that the node (and the picture) has the same size as the actual box enclosing `<text>`.

Then you can use those `<name>`s in a TikZ path (that should be `overlay`ed):

```
\tikz[remember picture, overlay]
  \draw (<name 1>) -- (<name 2>);
```

If you often simply connect two nodes and always the last defined you can make your life easier with the macros `\Tnode` and `\TnodeC` where the latter is like the first but also draws a path to the last node defined by the first.

If you don’t want to connect the last two nodes you give a coordinate/node name after the optional arguments of the edge.

An overview:

```
\Tnode[<optional node options>]{<node name>}{<node math>}
```

and

```
\TnodeC[<optional node options>]{<node name>}{<node math>}
                           [<optional edge options>]{<alternative target node for the edge>}
```

Of course, you can also use `to path={<anything>}` inside the `<optional edge options>` to overwrite anything (you don’t need to use `\tikztarget` or `\tikzstart`).

For unrelated edges, you can of course just use a separated `\path` as described earlier.

The `\TnodeC` has also a starred version where the vertical dimension of the path is taken into account. (In your case this would stretch `\left( … \right)` which is the reason why I used `\vphantom` in combination with `\TnodeC*` but you could also just use `\bigl( … \bigr)`.)

---

It is also possible to implement a syntax where the node names are enclosed in `(` and `)` but that makes the code slightly larger.

---

For various approaches to implement `\ncbar` see [Is there a TikZ equivalent to the PSTricks \ncbar command?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55068/16595).
I have used my `paths.ortho` library and its `du` path operator/style but feel free to replace it with any solution you want. (The `udlr/distance` is measured between the border of the node and horizontal (middle) part of the path.)

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} \usetikzlibrary{paths.ortho}
\makeatletter
\def\tnode@#1#2#3{%
  \node[inner sep=+0pt, outer sep=+0pt, anchor=base, name=#2, #1]{\m@th$#3$};}
\newcommand*{\Tnode}[3][]{%
  \tikz[baseline,remember picture]{\tnode@{#1}{#2}{#3}}\xdef\@tnodeclastnode{#2}}
\def\TnodeC{%
  \pgfutil@ifnextchar*%
    {\let\if@tnodec@overlay\iftrue\expandafter\TnodeC@\pgfutil@gobble}
    {\let\if@tnodec@overlay\iffalse\TnodeC@}}
\newcommand*{\TnodeC@}[3][]{%
  \pgfutil@ifnextchar[{\TnodeC@opt@{#1}{#2}{#3}}{\TnodeC@opt@{#1}{#2}{#3}[]}}
\def\TnodeC@opt@#1#2#3[#4]{%
  \pgfutil@ifnextchar\bgroup{\@@TnodeC{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}
                            {\@@TnodeC{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{\@tnodeclastnode}}}
\def\@@TnodeC#1#2#3#4#5{%
  \tikz[baseline, remember picture]{
    \tnode@{#1}{#2}{#3}%
    \path[overlay] (#2) edge[TnodeC edge/.try,#4] coordinate (@tnodec@aux) (#5);
    \if@tnodec@overlay
      \path (#2 |- @tnodec@aux) -- (#2);
    \fi}}
\makeatother
\tikzset{TnodeC edge/.style={
  du, udlr/distance=2ex, shorten >=+4\pgflinewidth, shorten <=+4\pgflinewidth}}
\begin{document}
Gummies cheesecake gingerbread. Jelly-o applicake cupcake. Marshmallow gingerbread jelly
 beans soufflé gingerbread. Sesame snaps apple pie chocolate bar chocolate gummies
 jujubes.
\[\textstyle
  R^{\alpha\beta} - \frac{1}{2} R g^{\alpha\beta} + g^{\alpha\beta} \Lambda =
  \frac{8 \pi G}{c^4 \mu_0} 
  \left( 
    F^{\alpha\Tnode {a}{\scriptstyle\psi}}
    F_{     \TnodeC {b}{\scriptstyle\psi}[blue,stealth-stealth]}
    {}^{\beta} + \frac{1}{4} g^{\alpha \beta} F_{\psi\tau} F^{\psi\tau}
  \right)
  \vphantom{
    F^{\Tnode  {@a}{\scriptstyle\psi}}
    F_{\TnodeC*{@b}{\scriptstyle\psi}}
  }
\]
Caramels halvah apple pie cookie pastry wafer lollipop croissant jujubes. Tart cupcake
 pastry. Gingerbread candy sesame snaps pastry oat cake jelly beans. Soufflé chocolate
 gummi bears.

\[
  \Tnode {aa}{\psi} \quad\TnodeC*{bb}{\pi} [out=30, in=150, looseness=10, <->]
\]
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Wot no tikzmark?

Comment: I see now that tikzmark has a \subnode macro, an \Rnode or \rnode equivalent.  I'll try that also.  Thanks.

Comment: @Dominic Actually the \subnode macro wouldn't be of use here.  The \subnode macro is intended to go inside a node of a larger TikZ picture.