# Tikz arithmetic progression

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I'm trying to do something like that to show a arithmetic progression (using TikZ):[image]

Thanks! :D

Comment: @percusse, for possible future answers. lol

Comment: Well done, @percusse. Now we can't edit the `thanks` out of the OP's post :p

Comment: Related: [Can TikZ emulate PSTricks' inline \Rnodes, scattered along a complex equation?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/133273)

Answer (score 5):

With PSTricks.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=20pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\psset{arm=8pt,arrows=->,nodesep=2pt,shortput=nab,labelsep=2pt}

\begin{document}
$
(\rnode{2}{2},\rnode{4}{4},\rnode{6}{6},\rnode{8}{8},\cdots)
\ncbar[angle=90]{2}{4}^{\scriptstyle 2}
\ncbar[angle=-90]{4}{6}_{\scriptstyle 2}
\ncbar[angle=90]{6}{8}^{\scriptstyle 2}
$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## Remarks

For some unknown reason, when using the `standalone` documentclass an error

```
! Missing $ inserted.
```

is thrown.

## Implementation

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{every picture/.append style={remember picture}}
\begin{document}
$(
\tikz[baseline=(n2.base)]{\node (n2) {$2$};},
\tikz[baseline=(n4.base)]{\node (n4) {$4$};},
\tikz[baseline=(n6.base)]{\node (n6) {$6$};},
\tikz[baseline=(n8.base)]{\node (n8) {$8$};},
\cdots)
$
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
    \path[->] (n2) edge[out=90,in=90] node[above] {$+2$} (n4);
    \path[->] (n4) edge[out=90,in=90] node[above] {$+2$} (n6);
    \path[->] (n6) edge[out=90,in=90] node[above] {$+2$} (n8);
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{1cm}

$(
\tikz[baseline=(n2.base)]{\node (n2) {$2$};},
\tikz[baseline=(n4.base)]{\node (n4) {$4$};},
\tikz[baseline=(n6.base)]{\node (n6) {$6$};},
\tikz[baseline=(n8.base)]{\node (n8) {$8$};},
\cdots)
$
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
    \path[->] (n2) edge[out=90,in=90]   node[above] {$+2$} (n4);
    \path[->] (n4) edge[out=-90,in=-90] node[below] {$+2$} (n6);
    \path[->] (n6) edge[out=90,in=90]   node[above] {$+2$} (n8);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Output

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

A solution using a variation of `\tikzmark`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\tikzmark[1]{\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base)]{\node(#1){#1};}}
\newcommand\arprog[3][bend left]{\tikz[remember picture,overlay,font=\footnotesize]{
    \draw[->,#1](#2.north)to node[above]{$+2$}(#3.north);
}}

\begin{document}

\[
  (\tikzmark{2},\tikzmark{4},\tikzmark{6},\dots)
\]

\arprog{2}{4}
\arprog{4}{6}

\end{document}
```

[image]