# Arithmetic progression in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf

How the following image could be generated in LaTeX? It is an arithmetic progression.

[image]

I don't have any idea how to do it. Can you help me?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\begin{document}

$$\begin{array}{ccccccc}
-1, & 2, & 5, & 8, & 11, & 14, & 17,\ldots
\end{array}$$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome. // A good way to start is to post your current code.

Comment: @MS-SPO I have posted my current code, but I don't know how to do it...

Comment: Great. // Here's a similar question with many solutions: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140813/tikz-arithmetic-progression?rq=1 . May be you need to consult the tikz manual for reference (search for: ctan tikz)

Comment: I've tried the codes on the link, but I get errors...

Comment: Is it important to render the horizontal brackets in teal?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I suggest you employ `\underbracket`, a macro provided by the [mathtools](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) package.

[image]

Speaking for myself, I think this expression would look better without the commas.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for '\underbracket' command
\newcommand\ub{{\underbracket[0.4pt]{,\quad}_{+3}}}

\begin{document}
\[
-1\ub 2\ub 5\ub 8\ub 11\ub 14\ub 17,\dots
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 15):

Using `\foreach` loops from Ti*k*Z, you can also make the whole thing automatic. In the following example, I defined a command `\arithmeticprogression` with four arguments:

1. (optional) The horizontal unit length of the `tikzpicture`, defaults to `1cm`.
2. The starting point of the arithmetic progression.
3. The step in the progression.
4. The number of numbers that should be written in the progression.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{ext.paths.ortho}
\newcommand*{\APsign}{+}
\newcommand*{\arithmeticprogression}[4][1cm]{%
    \ifnum #3<0
        \renewcommand*{\APsign}{}
    \else
        \renewcommand*{\APsign}{+}
    \fi
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=#1, every node/.style={inner xsep=0pt, inner ysep=1.5pt, anchor=base}]
        \foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \y using int(#2+(\x-1)*#3)] in {1, ..., #4}
            \node (\x) at (\x, 0) {$\y$\makebox[0pt][l]{,}};
        \foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \z using int(\x-1)] in {2, ..., #4}
            \draw[teal] (\z.south east) |-|[distance=-3pt] (\x.south west) node[midway, below, black] {$\APsign#3$};
        \node at ($(#4,0)+(1,0)$) {$\dots$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
\arithmeticprogression{-1}{3}{7}

\arithmeticprogression{2}{4}{4}

\arithmeticprogression{1}{-2}{6}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

A non-conventional use of `tabularray`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tblr}{
    colspec={*{15}{c}},
    columns={colsep=1pt},
    row{1,2}={rowsep=-4pt},
    row{3}={rowsep=2pt},
    cell{3}{even}={preto={+3}},
    hline{3}={even}{blue,wd=2pt},
    vline{2-Y}={2}{blue,wd=2pt}
    }
-1, && 2, && 5, && 8, && 11, && 14, && 17,&&\ldots\\
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\end{tblr}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very clever solution!

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thanks, I'm going wild with `tabularray` :D

Comment: tabularray - the source of a lot of joy :)

Comment: Can the underbracket be made thinner and of the same as color as in the OP's question?

Comment: @Simd with `wd=` you can choose any width you like, also the color `blue` can be changed into any color you like.